# Getting exception when updating the reviewers of a Pull Request azure devOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an active pull request in ADO, and want to update it using the API described here:

[Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#enable_auto-completion_and_set_other_completion_options)

So far, I can successfully update the title of the Pull Request.

```
{
    "title": "Foo"
}
```

I now want to update the reviewers, here is the request I am patching:

```
{
    "reviewers": [
    {
      "id": "myValidGuid"
    }

   ]
}
```

However I'm getting the following 400 error returned:

```
{
"$id": "1",
"innerException": null,
"message": "Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: You can only update reviewers, descriptions, titles, merge status, and status.",
"typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer",
"typeKey": "InvalidArgumentValueException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 0
}
```

I can't see what I've got wrong with my request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link you provided it looks like you are using the 'Pull Requests API' but you should actually be using the [Pull Request Reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20reviewers/create%20pull%20request%20reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#examples) API.

Per the documentation, the reviewerID is actually in the URI parameter:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/3411ebc1-d5aa-464f-9615-0b527bc66719/pullRequests/22/reviewers/{reviewerId}?api-version=5.0
```